# Why does all of my house water stop working when the washer is in use?

Tags: water

Why does all of my house water stop working when the washer is in use? Water is running in to the washer when in use but all the water like in the kitchen sink and in the bathroom is not working. Once the washer stop, all the water supply come right back around the house.

Comment: You didn't specify is you are on city or well.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. If you draw water in one place (e.g. the shower), does drawing water in another place (e.g. flushing the toilet) make the first place's water pressure get drastically lower? Or is it just the washing machine that lowers the rest of the house's pressure?

Comment: What Daniel Griscom said but I'm just going to assume that you have an inadequate water supply.  First, Have you made sure your master stopcock is fully open?  Max turns anti-clockwise will be fully open. If that's the case and you can't run **two taps at the same time** then your supply is almost certainly the problem.  The solution will require $$$ so get a professional opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have what's called a "vacuum breaker" or "anti-siphon" valve in your system somewhere that is intended to prevent water from being pulled back into your pipes when the pressure drops, and the washer feed is dropping the pressure enough to activate it.